# How to set up two Nginx containers as a reverse proxy in an active-passive set up with failover?

Tags: nginx, docker

I have set up a Nginx container on a Linux-EC2 server. My Nginx config file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name     client-dev.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://dev-client.1234.io:5001/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name     client-test.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://test-client-1234.io:5005/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```

It passes the requests with different ports to port 80. Now, I need to make a redundant Nginx in an active-passive mode. In case, if the Nginx container goes down/stops.

To do so, would I need to set another Nginx container in the same server? If so, how should it be setup to do the failover automatically?

I have looked at "upstream" option, but as I found, it would not work for this case. The proxy_pass that I have are external and dynamic that I get them using a script from docker-cloud.

There is another way named "docker-gen" however, I'm not sure how much useful it would be, and I prefer to use another way if there is any?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of following options:

1. Kubernetes: You can create a deployment for your nginx setup and use liveliness probes. Kubernetes will probe the nginx container with http request/interval you provide, if the pod is not healthy, it will be killed and recreated. Using multi nodes in your kubernetes cluster you can even mitigate from node failure.
2. Docker Swarm: Using docker swarm mode with multiple nodes, you can mitigate from node failure, but nginx health should be checked by an external custom script that can be done with `bash` and `curl`.
3. Using standalone hosts with keepalived: This is traditional nginx active/passive cluster using keepalived. You can also use this with docker but it would be dirty. because all of your containers will be passive on one host.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just faced with a problem: My nginx is stopped because one of services url, doesn't work and it gives this error: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream  although I don't have upstream option in my config file. any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: This usually means that the dns name you provided as upstream server cannot be resolved. To test it, log on nginx server and try pinging upstream server provided and see if the name resolution completes correctly, If its a docker container try `docker exec -it` to get a shell, then  try pinging the upstream to test the name resolution.

Comment: when the docker service is stopped, I can't use docker exec, I can use it if the container is running. That proxy-pass can not be resolved because it is down. but I have many other servers on the nginx-config file that needs to be worked how can I fix it

Comment: Try using ip in nginx config to test it out